# How do I start off the code for the form to calculate the payroll?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am a beginner at coding and recently took a part time course through a local college but I've also mistakenly taken a course meant for 2nd term.. I've managed to figure out some of the assignments but I am clueless on how to start off with this one. (This course was meant to be taken after 2 courses of learning java which I haven't even touched yet.)

---

The following script is what I've learned on a video in regards to this section but I'm not sure how to implement it onto the assignment but also feel like it's already been done.

```
function checkData(){
//  Validate the data
//  Retrieve the data from the DOM
    let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    let mark = document.getElementById("mark").value;

    mark = parseFloat(mark);
    if(name != "" && isNaN(mark)==false){
    displayData(name,mark);


    resetFields();


function displayData(name,mark){
//  Declare variables
    let passfail = "pass";

    // Create the elements using DOM methods
    let newTr = document.createElement("tr");
    let newNameTd = document.createElement("td");
    let newMarkTd = document.createElement("td");
    let newPFTd = document.createElement("td");

    if(mark < 50){
        passfail = "fail";


    // Add the data to the tds
    newNameTd.innerHTML = name;
    newMarkTd.innerHTML = mark;
    newPFTd.innerHTML = passfail;
    newTr.appendChild(newNameTd);
    newTr.appendChild(newMarkTd);
    newTr.appendChild(newPFTd);
```

---

The 2 tasks in this assignment as follows:

---

**Calculate gross pay

Starting in the calcPay() function:

Calculate the employee’s pay by multiplying their rate of pay by the hours worked.

If the hours worked are greater than 40, then calculate those extra hours at an increased pay rate of 50%.

For example, if someone worked 45 hours at $10 an hour, 40 hours would be  multiplied by $10, and 5 hours would be multiplied by $15 per hour.

---

**Precision
In the printRow() function:

Using the toFixed() method, convert the gross, tax, and net variables to be 2 decimal places.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Competency 17</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section id="content">
            <h1>
                Employee Payroll Entry Form
            </h1>
            <form id="payForm">
                <label for="">Full Name:</label><input type="text" autofocus id="fullName"/>        

<br />
                <label for="">Hours Worked:</label><input type="text" id="hoursWorked" /><br       
 />
                <label for="">Hourly Rate:</label><input type="text" id="hourlyRate" />
                <footer>
                    <button id="calcButton" type="button">Calculate</button>
                </footer>
            </form>
            <h1>
                 Employee Payroll Summary Report
            </h1>

            <table id = "employees">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Employee Name</th>
                        <th>Gross Pay</th>
                        <th>Tax</th>
                        <th>Net Pay</th>
                     </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", load);

function load(){
    let calcButton = document.getElementById('calcButton');

    calcButton.addEventListener('click', calc);
    clearFields();
```

}

```
function calc(){
    let name = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
    let hours = document.getElementById('hoursWorked').value;
    let rate = document.getElementById('hourlyRate').value;

    if(name == "" || hours =="" || rate==""){
        clearFields();
        return;
    }

    let pay = calcPay(hours,rate);
    let taxes = getTax(pay);
    let net = pay-taxes;

    printRow(name, pay, taxes, net);
    clearFields();
}

function clearFields(){
    document.getElementById('fullName').value = "";
    document.getElementById('hoursWorked').value = "";
    document.getElementById('hourlyRate').value = "";
    document.getElementById('fullName').focus();

}


/*
    calcPay function
    receives hours and hourly rate values
    returns the calculated pay
*/
function calcPay(hours, rate){
    let 
}

/*
    getTax function
    receives gross pay
    returns relative tax rate
*/
function getTax(funcGross){
    let funcTax = 0;
    if (funcGross<250){
        funcTax = funcGross*.25;
    }
    else{
        if (funcGross<500){
            funcTax = funcGross*.3;
        }
        else{
            if (funcGross<=750){
                funcTax = funcGross*.4;
            }
            else{
                funcTax = funcGross*.5;
            }
        }
    }
return funcTax;
}

/* 
    printRow function
    receives name, gross, taxes, and net pay
    formats currency
    prints a row in the table
*/
function printRow(name, gross, taxes, net)
{
    //  Set values to 2 decimal places here


    let tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let td = document.createElement("td");
    let td1 = document.createElement("td");
    let td2 = document.createElement("td");
    let td3 = document.createElement("td");

    td.innerHTML = name;
    td1.innerHTML = `$${gross}`;
    td2.innerHTML = `$${taxes}`;
    td3.innerHTML = `$${net}`;

    tr.appendChild(td);
    tr.appendChild(td1);
    tr.appendChild(td2);
    tr.appendChild(td3);

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

---

I've tried searching up different types of methods that I was able to find on how to calculate payroll but it seems that isnt what I'm required to do. What I think I need to do is just fill in the code that allows the payroll to be calculated and then added into a table below?

Comment: "I've also mistakenly taken a course meant for 2nd term" Talk to the administration and get switched to the proper course.

Comment: @ceejayoz its too late, I'm one month (out of 4) away from the end, I only learned about it when I booked an appointment with a tutor last week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example for calcPay()

```js
function calcPay(rate, hoursWorked) {
  let grossPay;

  if (hoursWorked <= 40) {
    grossPay = rate * hoursWorked;
  } else {
    grossPay = rate * 40 + (rate * 1.5) * (hoursWorked - 40);
  }

  return grossPay;
}

// Example usage:
let rate = 10; // dollars per hour
let hoursWorked = 45;
let totalPay = calcPay(rate, hoursWorked);

console.log(`The gross pay for ${hoursWorked} hours at $${rate} per hour is $${totalPay}.`);
```

An example for printRow()

```js
function printRow(name, rate, hoursWorked) {
  let grossPay = calcPay(rate, hoursWorked);
  let tax = grossPay * 0.15;
  let netPay = grossPay - tax;

  console.log(`${name.padEnd(10)} ${rate.toFixed(2).padStart(6)} ${hoursWorked.toString().padStart(6)} ${grossPay.toFixed(2).padStart(8)} ${tax.toFixed(2).padStart(6)} ${netPay.toFixed(2).padStart(8)}`);
}
```

Hope this helps!
-byteBat